# Where to load data in a Xamarin.Forms MVVM-Application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Where is the best place to put my data loading in a Xamarin.Forms MVVM-Architecture application? For example:

I'm using a Tabbed-Page with some ContentPages containing Pickers. The Pickers ItemsSources are bound to a ViewModel-Property. Where is the best place to put my logic of loading the Pickers ItemsSource-Data?

I could do it in the ViewModel-Constructor, but I don't think that's recommended since loading data in a constructor is simply bad coding. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any "loaded" on the page. Maybe the "OnAppearing" event can be used?

The loading of the data is asynchronous, and I'm not using any MVVM-Framework at all at the moment.

Comment: The best place to do it is on another thread, asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependant on the MVVM framework you're looking to use. I personally prefer [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm). This has a `Init` method you can override in your ViewModel which is an ideal place to load your data. It also provides you with easy navigation methods. The `Init` method is also the place you can pass data into when pushing new views onto the navigation stack. Besides that it also provides you with `ViewIsAppearing` and `ViewIsDisappearing` methods.

```
public override void Init (object initData)
{
    base.Init (initData);
}

public override void ReverseInit(object returnedData)
{
    base.ReverseInit(returnedData);
}

protected override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);
}

protected override void ViewIsDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsDisappearing(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I'm not using a MVVM-Framework at all, cause all my ViewModels are kept in a .netstandard 1.6 project and it seems that mvvm light and freshmvvm are forcing to put views and models in the same project, what i won't do. 

maybe you know when the init method of fresh mvvm is called?

Comment: It gets called when the built-in IOC container tries to resolve an instance of the PageModel. This is done through the `FreshPageModelResolver` class https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/master/src/FreshMvvm/FreshPageModelResolver.cs

Comment: Thank you. Thats nice, since I'm using autofac as IoC I can try to initialize theh view on the OnActivating event of the registered instances.